# Passing string into jni CallObjectMethod from c++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have narrowed down my problem as much as I can but have come to a standstill. Using JNI, I am attempting to call a jmethod on an instance of a jobject in c++ where the java implementation takes a string as an argument. The layout of my code looks like:

```
jstring text = env->NewStringUTF("Text to parse")
jclass Parser = getClass(env, "ParserClassPath"); //Invokes FindClass
jmethodID parse = env->GetMethodID(Parser, "parse", "(Ljava/lang/String;)LPathToReturnClass;"
jobject ParserInstance = invokeObj(env, Parser); //Custom method returns class object after calling its constructor
jobject model = env->CallObjectMethod(ParserInstance, parse, text) // I believe problem is in this call
```

The problem, I believe is showing itself inside of the CallObjectMethod inside jni.h. When debugging, before I enter CallObjectMethod, `text` has a value of some memory location like `0x1ba4a238`. The CallObjectMethod in jni.h looks like:

```
jobject CallObjectMethod(jobject obj, jmethodID methodID, ...) {
        va_list args;
        jobject result;
        va_start(args,methodID);
        result = functions->CallObjectMethodV(this,obj,methodID,args); //Check args here
        va_end(args);
        return result;
    }
```

upon reaching the "Check args here" comment line, In the debugger, args shows a value of some memory location and a bunch of random characters `0x00d3fd7c "#&\@a1\2$"`

My Question is, should these characters be the memory location or string I passed? If not, Is my passing of arguments correct or is there some other type I need to be using? I do not have a real understanding of what is happening at this level in the code, so if someone could help me understand what exactly this call is doing that would be helpful as well.

Comment: No, you shouldn't expect to see your address. Your code is OK. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function and here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/ (don't have time currently for a proper answer)

Comment: Then I have no idea why my callobjectmethod is returning null. I am positive this string works when running it straight from the jar and it returns the proper data structure. My class is found, class method is found, class object is initialized and method is called on it. I am at a loss for why this isn't working from c++ side.

Comment: use a debugger and set a breakpoint in the Java method. Probably something else is not what you think it is.